# About React 18 SSR (on Amazon S3)

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, server-side-rendering

This question is related to SSR in React 18.
I am deploying a React Application through a static file hosting system called Amazon S3.
However, after hearing about the SSR feature of React 18, I had a question.
Since S3 is not a real server, it does not function as a server. (it's just response files).
But speaking of SSR, the server must render HTML per request.
In this case, will I no longer be able to do static hosting in s3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AWS Lambda to deploy it.
here you can find some more information about how to it wroks:

https://sbstjn.com/blog/serverless-create-react-app-server-side-rendering-ssr-lambda/

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-server-side-rendering-for-react-in-aws-lambda/

Comment: That is mean I can not deploy react 18 + in s3 anymore If I need SSR feature Thanks!! I will use Lambda instead :)

Comment: Does AWS Lambda supports streaming? I wouldn't recommend Lambda for React 18 because the new SSR APIs like renderToPipeableStream and server components requires HTTP streaming.

Comment: @KevinHe Good point ! I also want to deploy a react 18 streaming SSR app. Would that work on AWS Lambda ?

Comment: @jaybe78 it won't work on AWS Lambda, not until the day lambda supports http streaming. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

now it is possible using AWS Lambda because it supports response streaming https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-response-streaming/